# Swiftでフォトライブラリから複数の画像を選択して取り込むにはどうすればいいですか？

Tags: swift

```
UIImagePickerController
```

ですと、1枚づつとなるのですが、
Swiftでフォトライブラリから複数の画像を選択して取り込むにはどうすればいいですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIImagePickerControllerは１枚ずつの選択しかできません。複数選択するためには繰り返すか、Photos.frameworkを使って自分でUIなどを含めて実装します。Photos.frameworkは写真ライブラリへのアクセスを提供するフレームワークです。

ただライブラリのアクセスからUIまで自分で作ることになるので、UIImagePickerControllerを使うことと比べるとけっこう大変です。

なので下記のような既存のライブラリを使うことも検討すると良いと思います。

https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker

Comment: ありがとうございございます！試してみます。

Comment: 空のプロジェクトをつくり使ってみたのですが、`present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)`のところで落ちてしまいます。DKImagePickerControllerも試してみたのですが、同じところで落ちてしまいます。

Comment: 使い方が間違ってるようですが、それ以上は情報が足りないのでわかりません。
コメントだと無理なので新しく質問を作って、エラーメッセージや現状のコードなどを載せましょう。

Comment: どうもすみません。